# Clonezilla Acronis GParted - clone bootcamp to SSD

Tags: clone, clonezilla

I tried to clone my bootcamp OSX/WIN7 HDD to a smaller SSD drive but failed on clonezilla and acronis.
I first prepped my HDD using `gParted` and made a smaller footprint (see picture below).
[image]

Clonezilla, on restore parts,  kept copying only the first segment and not the entire list of parts.

Acronis on clone setting, had errors as you can see from the picture below.  The first secgment sdc1 kept coming out as a failure

[image]

At the end OSX was bootable but windows never showed up in my select list. Also when i tried to repair windows, an error message kept coming up `windows cannot be reparied because of GPT`

[Tried this method](http://noahcoad.com/post/126/get-mac-os-back-onto-macbook-and-keep-windows-7-boot-camp-partition) but with no luck.  When i ran `rEFit` an error came up from the `partition tool` setting.
Does anyone have any tips on cloning a larger drive into a smaller SSD with bootcamp?  
**update:** sdc1 from the 2nd image did NOT come from factory. Im trying a second ssd with acronis and getting the same result.
With clonezilla, i had to first create 4 partitions to mirror my original disk using gParted. 
But then i could NOT boot to windows, got stuck on a page that said "disk error, press any key to restart"

Answer (score 1):

i wonder if that /dev/sdc1/ partition came from the factory.  Consider verifying that the destination SSD is completely blown away before imaging.

Comment: im not sure i understand what you are saying

Comment: @t-q A new harddrive could have come with a pre-existing partition, the one flagged msftres in the second pic.   Further Win7 uses GUIDs and gets really messed up when there exists a clone of the existing system in the existing system because the clone has the same GUID.  Make sure to boot with only one drive containing Win7.

Comment: what is the best way to completely clean out that SSD?

Comment: dban - Dereks Boot And Nuke which is commonly found as a special boot option on LiveCDs suchs as SysRescCD.org, omniboot, PartedMagic.  [link](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=partedmagic)

Comment: this would not be possible using windows diskpart?

Comment: Haven't used DiskPart in many years.  May have to be run from a DVD in some cases.  LiveCD is easier.

Comment: is LiveCD same as gParted?

Comment: gParted is a single program that is often on system rescue like LiveCD distributions.  There are thousands of different Linux LiveCDs, LiveUSB, and LivePXE implementations.  i would download the ISO image for PartedMagic and burn that ISO image such that when the computer is powered on, it boots off the LiveCD, not the harddrive.